# How do I push a command into an ssh session from a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cmd

Using a batch file, I want to ssh into example@0000, and then I want to execute a command in the server "example@0000".

My code looks like this:

```
1: @echo off
2: ssh example@0000       #this line works fine
3: ssh example_child@0000 #this line can only execute once the previous ssh is terminated.
```

Before my bat executes, my command line would look like this:

```
C:/home/username:
```

After line 2 executes, cmd will look something like this:

```
example@0000_bash $:
```

I now want the batch file to push line 3 INTO the current "example@0000" session, like this:

```
example@0000_bash $: ssh example_child@0000
```

The end result should look like this:

```
example_child@0000_bash $:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just inline your ssh command, the below will execute the second ssh on you example node.

```
ssh example@0000 ssh example_child@0000
```

Comment: Both ssh's need passwords. After I execute the new inline-style bat, it prompts me for my first password. After I enter that, the prompt just quits.

Comment: If you don't use shared keys you will need to add the password twice, once for each host

Comment: Again, after I log into the first ssh, the command prompt closes.